# How to override method from abstract class that uses generics for typing?

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract-class

My goal is to create an abstract class which has an abstract static method (which might get some basic implementation in the future), that i would like to override in a concrete class. It is a static method because it creates a 'copy' from a database model and parses it for use in the frontend. Although I can just return any types, I would like to constrain typescript to check that the parameters and return type are objects that extend 2 different classes, which is why i thought generics were the way to go. Therefore, the following code snippet exemplifies what i'd like to do:

```
export abstract class WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel<A extends WebModel, B extends Model>(dBModel: B): A {
        throw some error
    }
}

export class concreteWebModel extends WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel(dbModel: classThatExtendsModel): concreteWebModel {
        some implementation
    }
}
```

However, WebStorm indicates that concreteWebModel "incorrectly extends base class". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: Just to understand - why do you need to use generic for return type? Why defining return type directly as `WebModel` is not valid for you?

Comment: @BeniaminH, then it would not be possible to return the concrete class in the overriding method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, can you try

```
interface Model {}

abstract class WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel<A extends WebModel, B extends Model>(dBModel: B): A {
        throw 'some error'
    }
}

class concreteWebModel extends WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel<A extends WebModel=concreteWebModel>(dbModel: Model): A & concreteWebModel {
      return '' as unknown as A&concreteWebModel;
    }

    log() {}
}

let s = concreteWebModel.getWebModelFromDbModel(1 as any as Model);
s.log()
```

You can also remove generic type `A`, if you don't want to cast

```
interface Model {}

abstract class WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel<B extends Model>(dBModel: B): WebModel {
        throw 'some error'
    }
}

class concreteWebModel extends WebModel {
    public static getWebModelFromDbModel<B extends Model>(dBModel: B): concreteWebModel {
      return new concreteWebModel();
    }

    log() {}
}

let s = concreteWebModel.getWebModelFromDbModel(1 as any as Model);
s.log()
```

Comment: This way your method of concreteWebModel can return any WebModel, but it should return only concreteWebModel. Shouldn't it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys! This indeed seems to work so that is great! Not the biggest fan of the return as unknown as A&concreteWebModel. Is there no way to get that as just concreteWebModel?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This worked completely and was indeed what i was looking for. Might have just made it more complex using the generic type A, but did not know that i could return the WebModel and then the concreteModel could be returned in the concrete class. Thanks again

Comment: glad it helps .